# Codeignither Validation error

Tags: codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

Hello team I have a small issue and I would like to know the cause please see code below:

`<input type="text" class="span6" id="item_title"  value ="<?php echo  set_value('$item_title'); ?>">`

The preceding code gives me an validation error in Codeigniter however this code

`<?php echo form_input('item_title', $item_title); ?>`

It works fine with no validation error.The error indicates that the ***Item title field is required*** however i do not get this error with the latter script any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `set_value ()` takes field name and second take value you are providing only the field name since it is in single quotation do it something like this `set_value ('item_title', $item_title)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"  value="<?php echo set_value('firstname'); ?>" >
```

here for set value use like above example,where firstname in set_value('firstname') is name of input element